# CSS call from code behind not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, css, code-behind

I have the following entries in the css file.

```
a.intervalLinks { font-size:11px; font-weight:normal; color:#003399; text-decoration:underline; margin:0px 16px  0px  0px; }  
a.intervalLinks:link { text-decoration:underline; }  
a.intervalLinks:hover { text-decoration:none; }  
a.intervalLinks:visited { text-decoration:underline; }  
a.selectedIntervalLink { font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#003399; text-decoration:none; margin:0px 16px 0px 0px; }  
a.intervalLinks:active { text-decoration:underline; font-size:large ;  }
```

Edited for trial:

```
a.big-link:link{}
a.big-link:visited {}
a.big-link:hover{}
a.big-link:active{font-size:1em;}
```

Whenever i take the click on some  links (not shown) which is embedded in the webpage ..i can see the change in the link

```
a.intervalLinks:active { text-decoration:underline; font-size:large ;
```

(the font of the link will become large)

but after clicking the page refreshes ..the changes will go away

i want to keep the change for ever in that link ...even there is a page refresh

i understood that ..this can achieved only throughg the code behind of asp.net

Following code should work:but unfortunately its not ..could anyone help?

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            rptDeptList.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptDeptList_ItemDataBound);

        }

        void rptDeptList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.DataItem == null)
                return;
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            btn.Attributes.Add("class", "intervalLinks");  


        }
```

Edited for trial:

```
   void rptDeptList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Item.DataItem == null)
                    return;
                LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1");
                btn.Attributes.Add("class", "intervalLinks");  
                MyLinkButton.CssClass +=" big-link";

            }
```

Current html code for links has been shown below :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<div class='dtilsDropListTxt'><div class='rightArrow' ></div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WORK_AREA")%>  
CssClass="intervalLinks" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create an entirely new css class. When the item is clicked, remove the current class and add the new one. You can accomplish this client side using javascript or jquery quite simply, or codebehind. The former will save you a roundtrip.

Answer (score 1):

In your visited pseudo-selector of the link, type the changes you want to see, like

mylink:visited{text-decoration: line-through;}

Comment: its already there ..see my post 

a.intervalLinks:active { text-decoration:underline; font-size:large ;

Comment: see this:

a.intervalLinks:visited { text-decoration:underline; }

Comment: moreover, i need the change when i click.. that is most concerned here

Comment: I think pokrate is right. You need to change your definition of the visited state of the link. Once the page has refreshed, the link is no longer active, this is only a short state between clicking the link and the time it takes for the page to refresh. After that it's the visited state that you need to define.

Comment: i didnt get actualy, i need to edit my css class visited attribute ?
could you post here , what i need to edit?

Comment: a.intervalLinks:visited{text-decoration: line-through;}

Comment: i changed it , its not worked , now all the visited links become line through link,but still when i click the link the link become bigger for a momenet but after the page refreshes the change (bigger link) reset back to the line through link

Comment: a.intervalLinks:visited{text-decoration: line-through;font-size:large ;}  This would make all visited links large. But I think you want only the recently clicked link to be bigger. So add an extra class

a.big-link,a.big-link:link,a.big-link:visited,a.big-link:hover,a.big-link:active{font-size:1em;}

dont apply to any link. But apply it in your code-behind after checking the linkbutton id and then use 
MyLinkButton.CssClass +=" big-link";

Note the space in " big-link";

Comment: LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1"); 
                btn.CssClass = "intervalLinks big-link";

Comment: i did it ...still not hope ..same problem :-(

Comment: the solution given is correct. cnt say as something else is going on, and you cant express exactly what u want.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code behind.  First of all, `MyLinkButton.CssClass += " big-link"` was an example.  In your code, you do not have a button called `MyLinkButton`.  Instead, you should be using `btn.CssClass += " big-link"`, as `btn` is the button you are dealing with.

Secondly, your code will attach the `big-link` class to all of the link buttons, since you do not have a conditional that checks to see which button actually needs the new class.  When the link button is pressed, you'll need to store an Enum or something similar in the ViewState, so that in the DataBound event of the repeater, you can determine which link button should have the `big-link` class attached to it.